# Программа или утилита для сканирования на вирусы в сети

Tags: linux, вирусы, сканирование-портов

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема с вирусами в сети. Сервер у меня на Linux а рабочие станции само собой на винде. При помощи какой (бесплатной) проги или утилиты я могу просканировать сеть через сервер Linux и определить откуда лезут вирусы?! Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать антивирусные решения ClamAV (clamTK) и антивирусные решения от Avira (у них есть бесплатная версия для GNU/Linux).ClamAV/TK вы можете найти в репозитории своего дистрибутива. На счёт Avira, я видел её только в центре приложений Ubuntu.

Чисто из интереса. Что вам мешает проверить непосредственно компьютер? Например через LiveCD dr.web?

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к посту выше: при проверке/лечении рабочих станций, рекомендуется отрубать их от сети. В качестве бесплатного антивирусного пакета для Windows, могу рекомендовать Avast (для диагностики - AVZ). Наличие на linux-сервере антивируса считаю нецелесообразным.

Comment: Почему нецелесообразным?

Comment: А для чего он на сервере? Трафик проверять? Или дополнительно нагрузить сервер? Мой небольшой опыт использования антивирусной системы ClamAV показывает его крайне низкую эффективность в Windows-сетях. Могу быть не прав - поправьте!

Comment: Если на сервере имеется файло-помойка, то ее проверять не мешало бы. По причине того, что там могут быть вирусы, несмотря на операционку.

Answer (score 0):

Хочется добавить: остроумная тема в ловле вирусов - "[Honeypot](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28%E8%ED%F4%EE%F0%EC%E0%F6%E8%EE%ED%ED%E0%FF_%E1%E5%E7%EE%EF%E0%F1%ED%EE%F1%F2%FC%29)" (приманка). Имитация рабочей станции в сети, созданная только для того, чтобы обнаруживать вторжения: сканирование портов и т.п. Узнал из [этого поста](http://habrahabr.ru/company/symantec/blog/149904/) на Хабре.

Может помочь отследить «откуда лезут вирусы».

Comment: Вирусы лезут из этих ваших интернетов! Я гарантирую этот факт!

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует обратить внимание в сторону IDS/IPS. Установка и поддержание актуального состояния антивирусных програм на клиентских ПК -- это почти необходимость, иначе обрезать все права(инет, установка программ/железа, изменение сетевых настроек) на клиентских ПК